# SSO Plugin in Bitbucker Server how to kickstart authentication

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, atlassian-plugin-sdk, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to write a small bitbucket plugin that enables SAML 2 SSO authentication.

I've been looking at the source code of [sample authentication plugins](https://bitbucket.org/mheemskerk/stash-auth-plugin-example/src/4e6189b3eeddf814a4147a8c3888a1cdd10bb7ac/src/main/java/com/atlassian/bitbucket/auth/example/RemoteUserAuthenticationHandler.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) in bitbucket, and it looks quite straightforward.

However, my question is what is the best approach to handle authentication that spans over separate requests.

To do SAML SSO, you have to send a POST to the IdP via the user's browser, and then it sends a SAML token back via POST's again, but then you're no longer in the middle of authentication.  So I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to kickstart the authentication process again, my current thought is as follows:

1. Have my authentication handler that implements `com.atlassian.bitbucket.auth.HttpAuthenticationHandler` do a check to see if SAML authentication has happened in the `authenticate()` method, and then redirect them to the IdP if necessary. (Authentication process has stopped because of the redirect)
2. Receive the SAML token from the IdP on a separate servlet and check SAML token is good to use. Presuming it's all good, set a servlet request attribute (or session attribute) with the username that has been validated, and then forward the user to the original page they tried to access.  This should start the authentication process again.
3. My authentication handler runs again, checks for the request/session attribute, and this time creates the `ApplicationUser` that is necessary for `authenticate()` to complete successfully.

Does this sound like a good approach? I had a look at the bitbucket source code for how the Crowd SSO handler works, but with Crowd SSO it doesn't need to redirect you an external login page, so it doesn't have an example of this flow.

Ideas?

Comment: ping me when you release, also have you thought about adding SAML 2.0 to https://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd ?

Comment: I know you can use crowd, but crowd isn't free. I haven't bothered to implement this yet. But I may do it after June when things die down a bit at work.